# font-size in @media queries not applying

Tags: html, css, media-queries, font-size

I have managed to get the iFrame and body content width to change with the `@media` rule however I cannot get the font-size to adjust successfully. In my HTML my `@media` rules come after my style css in a seperate file. I cannot see what is preventing the `font-size` from changing the font-size.

JSFiddle (Broken):

http://jsfiddle.net/OliverNChalk/1a04Lx4g/

Style CSS:

```
#bodycontent {
z-index: 2;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
width: 80%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
}
p {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: lightgrey;
}
```

These are then the media rules:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 560px) {

    #bodycontent {
        font-size: 1em;
        width: 95%;
    }

    p {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 1em;
}

    iframe {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    #bodycontent {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        width: 95%;
    }

    iframe {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 85%;
    height: 400px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #bodycontent {
        font-size: 1.7em;
        width: 95%;
    }

    iframe {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
    }
    }
```

Any answers are much appreciated :)

Comment: Is the iFrame src in question part of your domain, or is it from another website? If it's from another website, you cannot manipulate the inner html of an iframe if it is cross-domain

Comment: This is not the problem in this case as i have simply been adjusting the padding on the outside of it. However the font-size is the main issue for me.

Comment: Manipulating the padding of an iframe is much different than manipulating the font-size which is _WITHIN_ the iframe. I ask again, is the iframe from your domain or not?

Comment: The font-size is wrapped in a <p> outside of the iFrame. Above the iFrame. <div id="bodycontent">
        <p>TexMex Resturant is located in Mona Vale. Our address is <em>18 Barrenjoey Road, Mona Vale NSW 2103.</em> Below is an interactive google maps to help you get around.</p>
        
        
                <div id="googlemaps">
            
            <iframe src="example.com"</iframe>
            
                </div>

Comment: It would be extremely useful if you provide all information in your question, also feel free to provide a JSFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max-width` is constantly being overridden as the screen size increases. However using `mind-width` is not being overridden as the CSS is lower down in the sheet. This uses CSS's cascading nature to override the irrelevant code.

e.g.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 840px)
```

Overrides the previous 720px rule. As the browser has met the requirement for the larger screen it runs the code overriding the previous statement.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    #bodycontent {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        width: 95%;
    }

    iframe {
    width: 90%;
    height: 600px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 840px) {
    #bodycontent {
        font-size: 1.7em;
        width: 95%;
    }

    iframe {
    width: 90%;
    height: 600px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are signaling for more than one media query at once. For example, you have one media query that asks if the max width is `1200px`. You then have another query asking if the max width is `840px`, and so on. What I am suggesting is that maybe, when you trigger the 1200px, you also trigger the 840px. Now, I am no CSS expert but I am just offering an outsider's standpoint. That's my 2 cents.

Good luck with figuring this out in the case that my answer is incorrect.

Best Regards,
Emanuel

Comment: Correct that media query is being overridden by the following queries. I will look into adding multiple media queries.

Comment: Yes you are correct, this is the problem and I have now found the fix thank you :)

Comment: Oliver, if you found the answer, please check right answer to expose your thanks to Emanuel :)

Comment: Good luck with the rest of your project Oliver!